# C# DataTable error

Tags: c#, database, list

I have a DataTable printed on a ListView, it was working fine, but at some point, it started trhowing theese errors. The workaround for this project is:

User fills the WinForms, then inserts on DataBase, when the user finish, the MainForm is shown, calling the `actualizarFormulario()` method, so the `ListView` is filled with the new data.

**EDIT**

The line 156 in this error is `item.SubItems.Add(row[1].ToString());` but it also gives me 153, 155... everything inside that foreach.

> 21-05 17:00 > Exception: Tipo: System.InvalidOperationException
>   Mensaje: Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not
>   execute. Origen: System.Data Stacktrace:    at
>   System.Data.RBTree`1.RBTreeEnumerator.MoveNext()    at
>   Operaciones_Diversas.Principal.actualizarFormulario() in C:\Documents
>   and Settings\usuario\mis documentos\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\Operaciones Diversas\Operaciones
>   Diversas\Principal.cs:line 156
>
> ---

The code for fill the data is this

```
private void actualizarFormulario()
{
    try
    {
        listaLotes.Items.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow row in Consultas.listadoLotes().Rows)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(row[0].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(row[1].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(row[2].ToString().Substring(0, row[2].ToString().Length - 2) + "," + row[2].ToString().Substring(row[2].ToString().Length - 2, 2)).ToString("N2", Cultures.Spain));
            item.SubItems.Add(row[3].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(row[4].ToString());
            listaLotes.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Logger.log(ex); }
}

    public static DataTable listadoLotes()
    {
        try
        {
            SelectBD sel = new SelectBD(Program.ConexBD,
            "SELECT referencia, tipo, total_lote, COUNT(Documentos.id) as Documentos, cuenta FROM Lotes"
            + " LEFT JOIN Documentos"
            + " ON Lotes.referencia = Documentos.ref_lote"
            + " WHERE Lotes.fecha_creacion='" + valoresGenerales.dateHoy + "'"
            + " GROUP BY Lotes.referencia, Lotes.tipo, Lotes.total_lote, Lotes.cuenta"
            + " ORDER BY Lotes.tipo"
            );
            return sel.DataTable;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.log(ex);
            return new DataTable();
        }
    }
```

**EDIT 2**

Using a  `for` loop, is increasing my program speed, and it can't be this way, because the user needs to interact fast with everything...

```
for (int i = 0; i < Consultas.listadoLotes().Rows.Count; i++)
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(Consultas.listadoLotes().Rows[i]["referencia"].ToString());
    item.SubItems.Add(Consultas.listadoLotes().Rows[i]["tipo"].ToString());
    item.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(Consultas.listadoLotes().Rows[i]["total_lote"].ToString()
        .Substring(0, Consultas.listadoLotes().Rows[i]["total_lote"].ToString().Length - 2)
        + ","
        + Consultas.listadoLotes().Rows[i]["total_lote"].ToString()
        .Substring(Consultas.listadoLotes().Rows[i]["total_lote"].ToString().Length - 2, 2)).ToString("N2", Cultures.Spain));
    item.SubItems.Add(Consultas.listadoLotes().Rows[i]["Documentos"].ToString());
    item.SubItems.Add(Consultas.listadoLotes().Rows[i]["cuenta"].ToString());
    listaLotes.Items.Add(item);
}
```

**EDIT 3**
Working Code

```
        listaLotes.Items.Clear();
        DataTable tabla = Consultas.listadoLotes();
        for (int i = 0; i < tabla.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
            item.SubItems.Add(tabla.Rows[i]["referencia"].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(tabla.Rows[i]["tipo"].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(tabla.Rows[i]["total_lote"].ToString()
                .Substring(0, tabla.Rows[i]["total_lote"].ToString().Length - 2)
                + ","
                + tabla.Rows[i]["total_lote"].ToString()
                .Substring(tabla.Rows[i]["total_lote"].ToString().Length - 2, 2)).ToString("N2", Cultures.Spain));
            item.SubItems.Add(tabla.Rows[i]["Documentos"].ToString());
            item.SubItems.Add(tabla.Rows[i]["cuenta"].ToString());
            listaLotes.Items.Add(item);
        }
```

Comment: You cannot modify collection in foreach. You must use normal for loop.

Comment: But as I said, everything was working perfectly, the errors started minutes ago, just by random...

Comment: Comment this line `listaLotes.Items.Add(item);` and everything will work again

Comment: @user1381537 `everything was working perfectly, the errors started minutes ago` - most probably before that the line `listaLotes.Items.Add(item);` was not reached for some reason, e.g. old code was running or `Consultas.listadoLotes().Rows` collection was empty.

Comment: if I do that, @aleksey.berezan the listview will be empty...

Comment: @user1381537, then you might try to use `for`-loop as @Stickman stated in the answer below

Comment: @user1381537, BTW, how the `listaLotes.Items` and `Consultas.listadoLotes().Rows` are connected? Because they should be, otherwise you wouldn't get this error(or I'm getting the situation wrong)

Comment: `listaLotes` is the ListView name, of course. `Consultas.listadoLotes()` is called in the `foreach` loop. Using a `for` loop, is increasing a lot the ListView refresh time...

Answer (score 6):

You're modifying the collection as you're iterating through the enumerable. Instead of a `foreach` loop, use a `for` loop instead.

Comment: With my for loop, the program is lot slower than before :S

Comment: ... Yeah, but taking 8 secs to load the MainForm is just, non-viable.

Comment: Your new code is hitting the database with every loop iteration. That will definitely slow you down. You need to instantiate the table you're iterating through as a local variable within the scope of the method.